# WSL gradle pre-pending current directory to Android SDK path

Tags: android-studio, gradle, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have set the terminal on Android Studio to use WSL, specifically the Ubuntu one. Running builds from the IDE provided buttons works fine for my project. I decided to start using the terminal more and would prefer to run the builds from there, so I tried running

```
./gradlew tasks
```

at the root of the project to test out the Gradle I had installed with sdkman in WSL, but I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> The SDK directory '/mnt/c/Users/Henry-PC/Desktop/DJ-Cloud/C:\Users\Henry-PC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk' does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

Any ideas as to what is wrong with?

Answer (score 0):

Just had this issue myself, I had a `local.properties` file that specified an incorrect directory.

After removing it entirely gradle is able to locate the Android SDK using the exported ANDROID_HOME environment variable